# How do I forcefully disconnect a client in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm testing SignalR (0.4.0 via nuget) and can't find any way to have the server forcefully disconnect a client.  I assume I'm missing something obvious.

My test code is below and I've tried both Close() and Timeout() in pretty much every place and combination I can think of with no success. The client continues to receive pulse messages, though I do always get 2 reconnections within the first 4-5 seconds that appear to come from `return Connection.Close()` in `OnReceivedAsync()`

Server:

```
internal class SignalRServer
{
    private Server server;

    public SignalRServer()
    {
        server = new Server("http://localhost:13170/");
        server.MapConnection<EchoConnection>("/echo");
        server.Start();
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimer;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        IConnectionManager manager = server.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IConnectionManager)) as IConnectionManager;
        IConnection connection = manager.GetConnection<EchoConnection>();
        connection.Broadcast("pulse");
        connection.Close();
        connection.Timeout();
    }
}

internal class EchoConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnConnectedAsync(IRequest request, IEnumerable<string> groups, string connectionId)
    {
        Connection.Timeout();
        Connection.Close();
        return Connection.Broadcast(String.Format("{0} connection", connectionId));
    }

    protected override Task OnReconnectedAsync(IRequest request, IEnumerable<string> groups, string connectionId)
    {
        return Connection.Broadcast(String.Format("{0} reconnection", connectionId));
    }

    protected override Task OnReceivedAsync(string connectionId, string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        Connection.Close();
        Connection.Timeout();
        Connection.Broadcast(data);
        return Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
internal class SignalRClient
{
    private readonly Connection connection;

    public SignalRClient()
    {
        connection = new Connection("http://localhost:13170/echo");
        connection.Received += OnReceive;
        connection.Closed += OnClosed;
        connection
            .Start()
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (!t.IsFaulted)
                    connection.Send("Hello");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Exception);
            });


        Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionId);
    }

    void OnClosed()
    {
        // never called
        connection.Stop();
    }

    void OnReceive(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Sample Client output:

> d7615b15-f80c-4bc5-b37b-223ef96fe96c connection
>   Hello
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   d7615b15-f80c-4bc5-b37b-223ef96fe96c reconnection
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   d7615b15-f80c-4bc5-b37b-223ef96fe96c reconnection
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   pulse
>   ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a specific string to the client to force the disconnect:

```
void OnReceive(string data)
{
    if(data.Equals("exit"))
    {
        connection.Stop();
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work, but I'm surprised there is nothing built in. The source for the Close() method suggests its sending a message to the client to disconnect but I cant get it to actually do so.

Comment: It's a bug in the .net client. Why are you trying to force connection close?

Comment: @dfowler I'm building a proxy app to sit between an existing socket based server and a mobile web client.  If the socket closes on the server I want to relay that disconnection to the client.  I'll go with nmat's suggestion for now and test close() again when I have an actual JS client to test against.  Cheers

Answer (score 5):

In .Net Core use

```
Context.Abort();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.hubcallercontext.abort

Comment: How do you get HubCallerContext ?

Comment: Does it invokes OnDisconnected action?

Comment: I don't know. We need to investigate

Comment: It seems to cause a `TaskCanceledException`. When used in the `OnConnectedAsync` method, it seems to still continue the connection and only throw the exception on the next RPC called on the hub. Tested on .Net core 3.1. Can someone confirm?